# Javascript .onclick not calling function

Tags: javascript, onclick, javascript-objects, onclicklistener

When I click on a button on my page, I am expecting it to show the email object in the console but it is not doing that.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.querySelector('#email-btn').onclick = email_select;
});
```

```
function email_select(id){
  fetch(`/emails/${id}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(email => {
    console.log(email);
  });
}
```

When I run for example, this code in the console:

```
email_select(3);
```

It shows me the email object so that tells me the function is working correctly but when I click on the button in the browser, it isn't showing me the email object in the console. I tried changing it from .onclick to:

```
  document.querySelector('#email-btn').addEventListener('click', email_select);
```

This didn't work either. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
I did add the #email-btn dynamically so it's not in the original HTML and I was actually wondering if that is what the real issue is. Below is how I dynamically added the #email-btn:

```
function load_mailbox(mailbox){

  // Show emails in mailbox
  fetch(`/emails/${mailbox}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(emails => {
    let output = '<div class="list-group">';
    emails.forEach(function(email){
      if(mailbox === "inbox"){
        if(email.body.length > 15){
          email.body = email.body.substring(0,15) + "...";
        } else {
          email.body = email.body
        }
        output += `
        <button type="button" id="email-btn" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
          <strong>${email.sender}</strong><br>
          ${email.subject}<br>
          ${email.body}
        </button>
      `;
      } else if(mailbox === "sent"){
        if(email.body.length > 30){
          email.body = email.body.substring(0,30) + "...";
        } else {
          email.body = email.body
        }
        output += `
        <button type="button" id="email-btn" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
          <strong>${email.recipients}</strong><br>
          ${email.subject}<br>
          ${email.body}
        </button>
      `;
      }
    });
    output += '</div>'
    var Emails = document.createElement('div')
    Emails.innerHTML = output;
    document.querySelector('#emails-view').appendChild(Emails);
});
}
```

Comment: Is the email button in the original HTML or added dynamically?

Comment: Your `email_select` is never receiving an ID. At least not what you probably expect it to be - it actually gets an event. Very likely the network call fails or if it succeeds (as in, `fetch` doesn't reject it), then the `.json()` fails.

Comment: `function email_select(id){` <-- that id is not an id.... It is the event object

Comment: @Barmar yes I created the email-btn dynamically. I edited my post to show how it is created. I'm thinking maybe because I didn't create it using the .createElement function it is not being recognised properly?

Comment: You're using the same ID every time through the loop. IDs have to be unique.

Comment: You should create each button with `createElement`, add the click listener to that variable, and use a closure to get the proper message ID to fetch.

Comment: @Barmar I'm not sure what loop you are talking about. The forEach loop is working fine really if that is the one you are referring to.

Comment: But it's creating multiple buttons with the same `id="email-btn"`. `document.querySelector("#email-btn")` will only return the first one.

Answer (score 0):

you have no id param in your onclick.
make the onclick like this so you can add a parameter.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
document.querySelector('#email-btn').onclick = () => email_select(id);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If you're finding the element by id, then just use `document.getElementById('email-btn')`
2. The first argument any event handler is going to receive is the 'Event'.
3. Not seeing your actual `email-btn`, it's hard to see how you give the `id` to the event handler, so how does your handler method know which `id` to use?
4. The `this`, within your handler, is a reference to the element having the onclick handler defined, unless you `.bind()` the method to another context.